# Assigning key and value to scope in constructor in Angular Dart component

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

Consider this dead-simple Angular Dart component:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgComponent(
    selector: 'el',
    templateUrl: './component.html',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    map: const {
      'foo': '@foo'
    }
)
class MyElement {
  String foo;

  MyElement(Scope scope) {
    scope['bar'] = 'bar';
  }
}
```

The `foo` field is passed as an attribute, and the `bar` 'field' is added to the `scope` in the constructor.

This allows for the following use in the view:

```dart
<div>{{ctrl.foo}}</div>
<div>{{bar}}</div>
```

`foo` needs to be preceded by `ctrl`, but `bar` does not. Having a field directly added to the scope seems like a poor pattern in this specific example, but is there a common use case for accessing the `scope` object in a component constructor and defining values in it?

Comment: Good question. I had the impression so far that this is mostly an inheritance from JS as AFAIK there were no class members (like your `foo`). It may be interesting to access properties that are not members of the component itself. I have not tested if `<div>{{$parent.xxx}}</div>` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is 'no'.  In fact, components should not need to access the Scope object directly.

This is an improvement over the syntax in AngularJS (1.0, 1.2).  In AngularDart, setting explicit `$watch`s from components as well as setting scope properties is mostly obsolete.

- Instead of setting scope properties, AngularDart uses the `publishAs` annotation to set properties on the scope (prefixed with `ctrl`).
- Instead of watches, components define mappings between element attributes and class members.

Accessing the `Scope` is still useful when writing directives.  e.g. `ng-repeat` would use the `Scope` object to create children scopes and set the `$index` property.